# How do you create a windows 10 install dvd with some programs already installed?

Tags: windows-10

This question should have been already answered somewhere, but I cant find it.

My situation is this. I have different hardware configurations in my PCs, and from time to time I have to reinstall a computer (W10x64 Pro, Office 2016, printers, anti-virus, network drives mapping, some windows tweaks). My idea was to create an install dvd once a year, and use that instead of installing each program separately.

I suppose dism should be used. Can someone help with the procedure ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Maybe [Ninite](https://ninite.com/) would work for you?

Comment: I have no idea where to start. Right now i'm slowly digesting the information here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deploy-a-custom-image
I'm keeping Ninite for further use, but my idea was to create a customized image.

Comment: You can also take a look at [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/), it's a bit closer to what you've described.

Comment: There are a number of ways to *slipstream* files into a Windows installation ISO. See http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-add-files-to-bootable-iso-in-windows/ or https://www.pcsteps.com/13667-slipstream-drivers-updates-custom-windows-iso/

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, but it took some time to test NTlite. I created an iso after adding windows configurations, updates, and a few programs. As a result, the installed windows vm reflects the changes I made and updates, but there is no sign of the programs that were supposed to be installed. 
I started another question here about that : https://superuser.com/questions/1332286/using-ntlite-to-slipstream-programs-in-a-windows-iso