# Using NTlite to slipstream programs in a Windows ISO

Tags: slipstream

I started by posting [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1329613/how-do-you-create-a-windows-10-install-dvd-with-some-programs-already-installed) question on how to create a Windows 10 installation DVD, with preinstalled software (office, antivirus, etc), and it was suggested to try NTlite. After a test, the windows installed (as a virtual machine) with the customized ISO, doesnt have the software I tried to have preinstalled. The windows custom configurations and updates, worked fine, but the software pre-installation is also very important.

I'll retrace here my steps and maybe someone can spot a mistake.

This is the source loading into NTlite :

[image]

This is the updates :

[image]

This is some of the windows configuration (adding user accounts etc) :

[image]

This is a few software I added for a test :

[image]

And the final configuration :

[image]

As I said, the resulting windows installation doesnt have the software I tried to have installed.

Ideally, one should be able to create an installation image based on a windows (vm maybe) where the software has already been installed, but I guess that doesnt exist.

Comment: I don't use the software you are asking about however, I would expect that the post setup automate installation would require at least a local admin account to be defined for it to log in and run all the "setup.exe" (though you appear to skip user creation step). Also from what I can see in the pictures, it will only run those files but if you are required to put any input ie, next next yes/no etc. it may not go through the wizards?

Comment: I have only ever used DISM to create a .wim image, and applied that image, to the system partition.  Of course, that is nLite is supposed to do (more or less)  Are you sure you performed the required steps, and used the ISO that was created, because it almost sounds like you used the wrong ISO.

Comment: Hi @TiO I created two admins (user and administrator - third image), but actually I did not configure autologin. It wasnt clear to me whether the software would be added already installed in the NTlite preparation, or added as a setup and installed afterwords during the proper windows installation. This second alternative isnt exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi @Ramhound I think i performed the required steps, and I used the right ISO because the windows customization I did was present in the installation. Can you post a link on how to do this using DISM ? Maybe it offers more possibilities ..

Answer (score 1):

I'm running this right now, point of fact.  I started with a stock windows installer on a usb flash, retail version, old build.  I then had to add the directory, then create an ISO from it.  Once finished, I used 7zip to extract that to a local folder on an ntfs drive (large image sizes require this step, as any Fat32 drive like my original usb won't work; it'll crash because the images are too big).  Once the extraction was complete, I added drivers etc to the setup and all other editions, and created an iso afterward.  I then repeated my extraction, deleting the original extraction.  From here, I made sure my desired edition was "loaded" with NTLite, as it had been converted to .wim image in the last steps.  I used this loaded edition to put in any remaining updates and drivers, then I added all features, services etc.  Lastly, I added only those programs that have unattended installers.  Others may not work right.  The file types are .MSI, and only a few have EXE extensions.  Look them over, you should be able to tell.  Don't put in OFFICE or other software, instead, focus on controllers for any hardware, and a few small tools.  I am adding Visual C Redistributable packages as far back as 2008 for backward compatibility with some older apps.  If you have a running system, I suggest you leave the app reinstalls alone and use a tool like PC mover to store all of that.  You can pull back just what you want later.  Finally, you need to make sure you make the windows .wim image of your chosen version back into an ESD, an Encrypted System Disk (compressed, not editable) image.  Make sure to select "create ISO".  Now give it about an hour to finish.  Then use rufus to make a usb flash drive installer from your new iso.  Select UEFI:NTFS partition types and GPT partition, but for a format of the drive, change ntfs down below to ExFat (extended FAT32 compatible).  Look up the instructionals for more info on rufus.